# Formatting string as date with leading zeros when needed T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to convert a string to date. The field is either 5 or 6 characters, depending on what month it is. Sample data from the field is as follows:

```
20185,
20186,
20187,
20188,
20189,
201810,
201811,
201812,
20191,
20192,
20193,
20194
```

I can easily pull the year out - it's always 4 digits on the left.
How do I pull the month number out? Is there another way to do it, other than using a case/if statement evaluating the length of the field?

Comment: The month is always "the rest". `SELECT RIGHT('00' + STUFF('20185', 1, 4, ''), 2)` -- any string problem in T-SQL that can't be solved with `STUFF` isn't worth solving.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked too! Thank you so much!

Comment: A [`date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) has a _day_, _month_ and _year_, but you are starting from just a _year_ and _month_. What _day_ do you expect in the `date`? And a `date` doesn't have leading zeroes, but can be formatted into a string with out without leading zeroes. That makes the title and question somewhat at odds.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is to use [`datefromparts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @Str varchar(10) = '20198'

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(
    LEFT(@Str, 4), 
    SUBSTRING(@Str, 5, 2),
    1
    ) As TheDate
```

result:

```
2019-08-01
```

SQL Server will implicitly convert the strings to ints, so you don't need to mess around with adding leading zeros.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring()`:

```
select left(yyyym, 4) as yyyy,
       substring(yyyym, 5, 2) as mm
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column is always 5 or 6 characters, you can substring the value starting at the 5th index. See my example:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (datestring VARCHAR(6))
INSERT #temp (datestring) VALUES
(20185), (20186), (20187), (20188), (20189), (201810), (201811), (201812), (20191), (20192), (20193), (20194)


SELECT datestring,SUBSTRING(datestring, 5, LEN(datestring))
FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have used LEFT function, you can use RIGHT function as well. You just need to find out how many characters you want from the right side. Since you know first 4 characters of a string will be the year, you can subtract the length of string with 4.

Here is an example.

```
DECLARE @Str_Date VARCHAR(6) = '201810'

SELECT LEFT(@Str_Date, 4) [Year], RIGHT(@Str_Date, LEN(@Str_Date)-4) [Month]

GO 

DECLARE @Str_Date VARCHAR(6) = '20185'

SELECT LEFT(@Str_Date, 4) [Year], RIGHT(@Str_Date, LEN(@Str_Date)-4) [Month]
```